# What is wrong here? 'end' expected near '<eof>'

Tags: lua

Playing around in a game engine right now and when trying to run the game I get this error.

Here's my code:

```
DrawText("Hello World!",1,1, DrawMode.Tile, "large",5)
function Draw()
RedrawDisplay()
PlaySong(0,false)
local speed = 5
local nextPos = 0
function Update(timeDelta)
nextPos = nextPos + (speed) * (timeDelta / 100)
function Draw()
RedrawDisplay()
DrawSprite(02, nextPos, 8)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function Draw()
```

starts a function definition. It must be completed with an `end` to denote the end of its body.

like

```
function Draw()
  -- draw someting
end
```

Same for `function Update(timeDelta)`

I guess you're confusing [function calls](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.10) with [function definitions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.11).

Please read the Lua manual and do a beginners tutorial.

There is no point in editing and running code if you do not know the very basics of Lua.

Comment: Thank you! I did manage to get it to work after your help. Where do you think would be a good place to look for basic Lua tutorials?